# На сколько безопасно использовать NSDate в качестве ключа NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Из сервера приходят данные с датами в виде массивов и Dictionary в таком виде:

```
{
    "2016-05-08T00:00:00+03:00": 1,
    "2016-05-09T00:00:00+03:00": 2,
    "2016-05-10T00:00:00+03:00": 3,
    "2016-05-11T00:00:00+03:00": 1
},
{
    "2016-05-08T00:00:00+03:00",
    "2016-05-09T00:00:00+03:00",
    "2016-05-10T00:00:00+03:00",
    "2016-05-11T00:00:00+03:00"
}
```

На сколько безопасно хранить и обрабатывать данные в **NSDate**, если значимой частью является только дата? Есть подозрение, что это очень нестабильный формат данных, из-за которого могут появится ошибки у пользователей в другой time-зоне

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что безопасно, но я бы в качестве ключа использовал такое

```
NSNumber *key = @([[dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr] timeIntervalSince1970]);
```

оно точно будет одинаково везде, независимо от таймзоны.

Answer (score 0):

Если значимая часть только дата, то и используй в качестве ключа только дату( `yyyy-MM-dd`). 
Так будет правильней и понятней чем секунды.

Но убедись, что дата уникальна.